# How can I make the div scroll only horizontally?

Tags: scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have this :

[My HTML and CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/bC7dc/)

I want it to scroll horizontally only... how can I do this?

*HTML*

```
<div id="boxchap">
    <h3>Chap~</h3>
    <div id="center">
        <div id="fulllist">
        <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 17</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 16</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 15</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 14</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 13</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 12</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 11</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 10</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 9</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 8</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 7</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 6</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 5</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 4</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 3</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 2</a>
        </div>
            <div id="boxchap" class="listchap">
            <a href="#">Mujaki no Rakuen – Chap 1</a>
        </div
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#boxchap {margin-bottom : 140px;}
#boxchap .listchap {width : 230px;margin:0px 1px 0px 0px ;padding: 3px;float: left;border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;}
#center {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;width: 100%;padding-left: 3%;}
#fulllist {min-width:100%; height:140px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your css-class: #boxchap

```
overflow: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Now it should be scrollable horizontally.

You may also need to add for IE8:

```
-ms-overflow-y: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your css-class: #boxchap

```
overflow: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: @user3468742 horizontal scroll only know u have now..?